# XJC Generated Java class does not have primitive boolean type

Tags: java, ant, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have an XSD file with a data definition. Based on the XSD file, an ant-based target executes an XJC command to generate a Java class from XSD.

The problem I am having is for the XSD `<attribute>` tag; when I set the default to 'true' it takes wrapper Boolean instead of primitive boolean.

```
<xs:element name="TagElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="booleanAttr" type="xs:boolean" default="true" >
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The above XSD definition generates wrapper Boolean.

When `default` attribute is not there and instead I have `required="true"` then it works fine. So, this works fine:

```
<xs:attribute name="booleanAttr" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
```

How to fix this? How can I make sure that generated Java class has boolean primitive type instead of wrapper Boolean?

Generated Java code from XSD:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "booleanAttr")
protected Boolean booleanAttr;

public boolean isBooleanAttr() {
    if (booleanAttr == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return booleanAttr;
    }
}

public void setBooleanAttr(Boolean value) {
    this.booleanAttr = value;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with Boolean as the type for the field? It doesn't hurt, and it is *required* to have a way of storing that the element is absent after unmarshalling. The getter has type boolean, and the setter uses autoboxing.